# SHA1withRSA NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, android, rsa, sha1

Hi I have the following function to convert a string into a PrivateKey in my application:

```
public static PrivateKey main() throws Exception {
    // Read in the key into a String
    StringBuilder pkcs8Lines = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(PRIVATE_KEY));
    String line;
    while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
        pkcs8Lines.append(line);
    }

    // Remove the "BEGIN" and "END" lines, as well as any whitespace

    String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\n+","");

    // Base64 decode the result

    byte [] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.decode(pkcs8Pem, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // extract the private key

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("SHA1WITHRSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    return privKey;
}
```

and I get the following exception:

> W/System.err: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA1withRSA KeyFactory not available
>   W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyFactory.(KeyFactory.java:161)
>           at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:195)

so I have tried to find all the alghoritms I can use through this code:

```
        TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
        for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices())
            if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
                algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());
    for (String algorithm : algorithms)
        System.out.println(algorithm);
```

and in the response "SHA1withRSA" is included, do you know where the problem is?

Comment: There's no KeyFactory in the code you posted, and you only posted a portion of the stack trace. Post the *entire* stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

SHA1withRSA is a signature type, you see that in the list because you have

```
if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
```

If you edit that to

```
if (service.getType().equals("KeyFactory"))
```

you should see a list that looks something like this

```
DSA
EC
RSA
RSASSA-PSS
X25519
X448
XDH
```